# Why does the ADC overflow when using an external Aref?

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread

I'm using an LM35 temperature sensor, and it outputs 190 mV (which agrees with 19°C). I'm using an external reference voltage which I measure as 417mV. (This is set by the pin "aRefCntrl"). So I should have a reading around 467, but I get 1023, i.e. the ADC overflows. When I use the internal 1.1V reference I get a correct reading. Any ideas?

This is my code (Arduino waits for a request from the PC to send the data):

```
#define lm35 A0
#define aRefCtrl 10

void setup() {    
  pinMode(aRefCtrl, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(aRefCtrl, 0);
  analogReference(EXTERNAL);
  analogRead(lm35); // dummy read
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}  

void loop() {
  if ( Serial.available() ) {
    Serial.read(); // PC's request is a single byte
    int temperature = analogRead(lm35);
    Serial.println(temperature);    
  }
}
```

**follow-up** on Ignacio's comment: would a decoupling capacitor do? (I can't test for the moment, I have to order some)

Comment: How much current is available from the reference?

Comment: @Ignacio: not much, the reference voltage comes from a 10k/1k divider on 5V. Isn't the voltage I measure at the aRef pin not the real reference voltage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum reference voltage is 1.0 V according to the atmega328 [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf). See table 29-15. ADC Characteristics.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for that information in the datasheet, scanning it for all occurrences of "Aref", but it seems to appear as "Vref" :-). (Page 310, FTW.)

Comment: Hmm, Aref as in Analog Reference and Vref as in Voltage reference I think? But indeed 1.1V bandgap is a reliable (small voltage) source.